# Obtaining the oldest person from record list in SML

Tags: list, record, sml

I am trying to get the oldest person from the list of records in SML. I have started as I would with a simple list:

```
type person = {age:int, name: string} list

val p:person = [{age=11, name="Marco"},{age=12, name="Polo"}]

fun maxAge [] = NONE
  | maxAge [x] = SOME x
  | maxAge (p1 :: p2 :: xs) = if #age(p1) > #age(p2) then
                                       maxAge (p1 :: xs) 
                                     else
                                       maxAge (p2 :: xs)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: unresolved flex record
(can't tell what fields there are besides #age)
```

I thought p1 and p2 would be first and second elements of the list, in my case a record of name and age {age=11, name="Marco"}, and that I could easily access value by #age(p1) and then send the full record p1 deeper into the recursion, but that is not the case. Why?

Any tips would be highly appreciated.

PS: How can I print only the name string when I get the right record, this does not work:

```
maxAge [x] = SOME #name(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711264/sml-function-on-record-list?rq=1), the problem was that you can't pattern match "p1" and record, instead it has to be done like this:

```
...
maxAge ({age= p1, name= n1} :: {age= p2, name= n2} :: xs)
...
```

Then you can use "p1", "p2",... to proceed.

Comment: There is at least one other option: you can give explicit type to your `maxAge` function